# Can't control volume on HomePod minis

Tags: appletv, bug, homepod

Suddenly I’m unable to control the volume on my HomePod mini stereo pair. I press the volume buttons on my remote and get no change in volume. Generally the volume change indicator doesn’t appear either, though *sometimes* it does, but only after a delay (of up to a few minutes!).

I’ve restarted everything and even removed and re-added my HomePod minis (twice). All this started after (though not immediately after) updating to tvOS 15.

Is tvOS 15 broken? Is this a known problem?

---

ATV 4K (2nd) ; tvOS 15